# Bad request with retrofit when using no arguments and no body, how is this possible?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

I am facing a very odd behaviour with my project.

I am using retrofit v2.6.0

and Im doing a code like this:

```
@GET("{department}/details/")
    fun getCouponDetailHistory(@Header("Authorization") token: String,
                               @Path("department") department: String): Deferred<Response<Any>>
```

I call it from a service, of course sending the parameters.

I enabled the debug mode to track the query and I see this:

```
INFO  [2019-08-02 10:03:13,132] okhttp3.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://my-url/departmentId/details
INFO  [2019-08-02 10:03:13,405] okhttp3.OkHttpClient: <-- 400 Bad Request https://my-url/departmentId/details (272ms, unknown-length body)
```

If I use postman with a super simple request with other than the URL and the Authorization token (that I get it from my code as well to know is the same) it works.

Its hard for me to understand how I can be having a bad request here, might be my configuration?

I have it this way.

```
fun retrofitClient(baseUrl: String): Client = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())

        //.addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(jsonMapper))
    .addConverterFactory(
        GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
        .create()
```

as you can see I had previously added the JacksonConverterFactory.

It works for a POST endpoint I have but not for my GET.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after I time I found that there is a missing header on the client.

I added it this way

```
 @Headers("Accept: application/json")
 @GET("myurl")
```

This solved the problem

Comment: Well, glad you solved your issue. Yet this was only related to your back-end handling of the headers. I'm not even sure keeping this question open would help anyone :/

Answer (score 0):

Use below code converter for Void response in kotlin. Since there is no official support to void response from Retrofit.

```
    object UnitConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {
  override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type, annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
      retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
    return if (type == Unit::class.java) UnitConverter else null
  }

  private object UnitConverter : Converter<ResponseBody, Unit> {
    override fun convert(value: ResponseBody) {
      value.close()
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2329)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! but the response type Any is actually a generic

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that / after details is the issue.
Please remove / after details `@GET("{department}/details/")` and restart your application it would work. It is giving 400 because in the request you are not passing that extra / after details. `https://my-url/departmentId/details (272ms, unknown-length body)`